# Can't add external network to list of approved networks under google-cloud-sql-access-control

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When I try to authorize external network, the ip address that I am trying to add (public IP of php server that I need to connect to google-sql) is accepted by javascript but when I click "add" I get "could not perform operation"  If I try append /0 to the ip (or any other number, it seems) the javascript says "Not a valid subnet. Use CIDR (slash) notation (eg 200.27.123.0/24)" and the "add" button becomes unavailable.

For the time being, I have added 0.0.0.0/0 (amazingly, it takes that) in order to continue dev but I can't leave it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want /32 in that case. Or just the IP address without the routing prefix. Please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation